# Rails Dynamically Changing Collection Select In Form Based on form field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, collections

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app that tracks calls and each call has a pickup and dropoff facility from the Facility model which is an association.

In the call model there is an association for the Region model (i.e. Houston, Dallas, Austin, etc) where we select a region based on where the call is coming from.

What I'd like to do is be able to select a specific region (i.e. Houston) and in the pickup facility collection only show Houston region facilities.

I'm assuming to start off with I'd need to setup a relationship between Facility and Region as such:

**facility.rb**

```
attr_accessible :region_id
belongs_to :region
```

**region.rb**

```
has_many :facilities
```

Then I'd need to set each facility with a region_id that matches the respective region (i.e Houston, Dallas, etc) so the association works properly.

What I'm unsure of is how to select the specific region and only have the facilities in that region display in the form.  I'm assuming I would use some jQuery/JS/Ajax here to make it happen but not sure how to make it work.

Here's an excerpt of what my call, facility, and region models currently look like:

**call.rb**

```
belongs_to :transferred_from, :foreign_key => :transfer_from_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
belongs_to :transferred_to, :foreign_key => :transfer_to_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
belongs_to :region
```

**facility.rb**

```
has_many :calls_transferred_from, :foreign_key => :transfer_from_id, :class_name => 'Call'
has_many :calls_transferred_to, :foreign_key => :transfer_to_id, :class_name => 'Call'
```

**region.rb**

```
has_many :calls
```

Here's an excerpt of what my call form partial looks like:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :region %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:region_id, Region.all, :id, :area, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select', required: true}) %>
  <%= f.label :Transfer_From %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:transfer_from_id, Facility.active.order("facility_name ASC"), :id, :facility_name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'}) %>
 <%= f.button "Submit", class: 'btn btn-info btn-large', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Processing..."} %> 
<% end %>
```

If any of this is confusing or needs clarification, please let me know.  To summarize, I'm trying to select a region (Houston) and only show the Facilities that are in the Houston region in the form when that region is selected.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips you can provide.

Comment: I think this [Railscast:Dynamic Select Menus](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) might be a step in the right direction, but I'm not sure I would be using grouped_collection_select or not.

Comment: I've setup my associations between Region and Facility and that part works properly, now just need to figure out some jQuery/CoffeeScript to make this happen and what method to use in my form to select.  grouped_collection_select isn't doing what I need it to it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the Railscasts dynamic select menus I've come up with the following:

**calls.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  facilities = $('#call_transfer_from_id').html()

  $('#call_region_id').change ->
    region = $('#call_region_id :selected').text()
    options = $(facilities).filter("optgroup[label=#{region}]").html()

    if options
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').html(options)   
    else
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').empty()
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :transfer_from_id, Region.order(:area), :facilities, :area, :id, :facility_name, {include_blank: true}, class: 'select' %>
```

The problem with the above grouped_collection_select is that it's calling :facilities which lists all the facilities, I need to call the equivalent of Facility.active (scope I created on Facility to only list active facilities).  How can I call this from within grouped_collection_select?

So far in a new call I'm able to select the region then the facilities for that region show up only in the from field (transfer_from_id being called).  When editing the call and trying to change the facility I'm presented with a full list of facilities grouped by region instead of just the facilities for that region.  If I want to narrow it down I have to change region then change it back to the original for the specific region's facilities to show up solely.

I think I'm making progress with this, but it's not working out the way I want it.  I'm really open to answers that make more sense and are more clear.

Comment: Ah okay, i do like the answer here, as it's cleaner then what i wrote :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working for the most part but I'm still trying to figure out how to call Facility.active in the grouped_collection_select helper.  It only lets me pass :facilities which returns all Facilities.

Comment: Ah, you can probably get around that by setting up a method in your Region class. `def active_facilities; self.facilities.active; end;` and then instead of :facilties, put :active_facilities

Comment: @agmcleod using this method seems to have solved my issues.  Took me a second to figure out why I was writing a method in the Region model, but it's an association and makes sense now :)  Now if I could only figure out when editing a call to only show the facilities by region without having to switch regions and switch back to get the finite list. :)  Making progress. woot!

Comment: Basically what the view method does is takes the symbol, and invokes send on the object. It's how you can metaprogram method calls. Similar to javascripts' call()

Comment: Ah I get it now.  Thanks for taking the time to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I typically keep it real simple by loading a dictionary in the client, and just reference that.

So in your view, you can build out something like this:

```
<script>
  var facilitiesForRegion = {};
  <% Facility.all.each do |facility| %>
    var region = facilitiesForRegion[<%= facility.region_id %>];
    var object = { id: <%= facility.id %>, name: '<%= facility.facility_name %>'};
    if (region) {
      region.push(object);
    }
    else {
      facilitiesForRegion[<%= facility.region_id %>] = [object];
    }
  <% end %>

  $("#call_region_id").on("change", function (e) {
    var id = parseInt($(this).val());
    var facilities = facilitiesForRegion[id];
    $('#call_transfer_from_id').children().remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < facilities.length; i++) {
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').push('<option value="'+ facilities[i].id +'">'+ facilities[i].name +'</option>');
    }
  });
</script>
```

It's a little ugly. I'm not the biggest fan of building out an array of data in the view like that, but it works and avoids waiting ajax requests.

Be sure to double check the ids of the drop downs. I was guessing on that, based on field names and the for_for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I've put this in my _form.html.erb view and so far have had no luck with it.  When I select a region the facilities do not change to the specific region's facilities.

Comment: Is it after your form for? Are you getting any errors in your javascript console? (Check firebug/chrome dev tools). Try debugging as well, set a breakpoint inside the change event, see how it goes.

Comment: I had it before my form_for statement.  Should it be after?.  I checked the console in Chrome and I do not see any JS errors or problems so far.  I also posted an answer that I was able to get working, but it's not really what I want.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, should be after, or wrap the code in a document.ready. The dom elements have to exist in order to bind events to them.