# Rails 3 update_all with condition in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app with a Facility model and I need to update the region_id in the Facility model based on a field called facility_name.

So I'm trying to update all Facilities where facility_name starts with DFW.

In the console I tried this:

```
Facility.where("facility_name: ilike 'DFW'")
```

This gives me nil or a 0 record return.

I'd like to be able to do something like this to update the region_id in the Facility model:

```
Facility.where("facility_name: ilike 'DFW'").update_all(region_id: '1')
```

But this doesn't work because my where method reports a 0 count even though there are plenty of records with the facility_name beginning with DFW.

Is my syntax wrong or is this not possible to do in Rails 3?  If not, how would I go about updating over 100 records with this region id without doing it using crud/rails_admin?

I asked a similar question on how to use update_all but it didn't cover the conditional part.  Hope this is not considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're kinda mixing up syntax.

When you put a where condition in a string, you need to conform to the syntax of your database adapter. So for postgres which has ilike, you need to do:

```
Facility.where("facility_name ilike 'DFW'")
```

The colon is used when you pass a hash instead, but one can't do like statements:

```
Facility.where(facility_name: 'DFW')
```

Note that if you want the ilike to check for any rows that contain that value in the column, you need trailing & leading percent signs.

```
Facility.where("facility_name ilike '%DFW%'")
```

From there you can perform the update_all

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  `Facility.where("facility_name ilike '%DFW%'")' did the trick.  I should have looked at my search method in my model for the ilike syntax.  It's a bit early and my brain isn't wired, I should have known this.  Thanks for pointing it out to me. :)

Comment: No worries. When you look at the log files, or use rails console, you can usually see the SQL query created. Good way to know if your active record code is correct :)

Comment: Good point, I should also remind myself not to do any development until my second cup of coffee. :)

Comment: Now if you can help me figure this out, I'll buy you a coffee/beer :)  [Rails Dynamically Changing Collection Select in form based on form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533792/rails-dynamically-changing-collection-select-in-form-based-on-form-field)